# create a view with map / reduce functions that return values

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I would like to create a view with map / reduce functions that return the latest values from several documents with same id, seems I can return the latest document giving with the xyz id based on the update_datetime, not sure how to get the latest value like field1 and field2, thank you

```
doc1: id='xyz', field1='v1.0', field2='v2.0', field3='v3.0', status='NEW', update_datetime='2015-04-28'
doc2: id='xyz', field2='v2.1', field3='v3.0', status='CHANGED', update_datetime='2015-05-01'
doc3: id='xyz', field3='v3.1', status='CLOSED', update_datetime='2015-05-10'
```

define a view with map / reduce that, given a key value 'xyz', returns the following document:

```
id='xyz', field1='v1.0', field2='v2.1', field3='v3.1', status='CLOSED', update_datetime='2015-05-10'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the data model you have could be improved but I do not know enough about your use case to comment on that really. Therefore I would suggest a reduce function that will perform a merge of the documents using newer as an override for existing properties unless a property does not exist.
Here is the content of map and reduce functions (btw, I have changed the name of one of the fields from `update_datetime` to `updated`. Also please bear in mind that `id` and `_id` are different - might be worth renaming your own id field to something more distinguishable from couchdb's doc id field):

```
// MAP
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.id, doc);
}
// REDUCE
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    if (values.length > 1) {
        var mergedDoc = values[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            var newDoc = values[i];
            var updatingWithNewer = newDoc.updated >= mergedDoc.updated;
            for (key in newDoc) {
                if (key != "_id" && key != "id") {
                    if (updatingWithNewer || mergedDoc[key] == undefined) {
                        mergedDoc[key] = newDoc[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return mergedDoc;
    } else {
        return values[0];
    }
}
```

Performing level 1 reduce will give you expected result. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Seb, great thanks for your advise and it is works, for this part which do not include id:  I tried if I use if (key != "_id) in stead of  if (key != "_id" && key != "id") , it is still works, thank you

Comment: Hi Seb,  I have thousand of documents in my local couchdb, when I start to build using above view and reduce, it has some the following error, can you advise me on this?   thank you for your help {"error":"reduce_overflow_error","reason":"Reduce output must shrink more rapidl
y: Current output: '[{\"_id\":\"9f71c5fd408a255307415e87253d08d7\",\"_rev\":\"1-
c665502ad2e7aa78fd917951e9b12f37\",\"docType\":\"CO'... (first 100 of 919 bytes)
"}

Comment: As the message says, the reduce function is expected to reduce number of documents produced in each iteration. If you have plenty of unique documents that cannot be merged, that reduce function would not meet its expectations. I cannot tell you exactly by how much it is expected to shrink the outputs but I am sure you can find info on that in the docs.

Comment: BTW, I have a feeling that your data model could be somewhat improved. Looks to me that your documents represent some kind of a set of versions of software and you simply want to keep history of upgrades / changes?
Would you mind shedding some light on your use cases?

Comment: Hi Sed, can you help me take a look on this question? thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337113/how-to-get-from-couchdb-only-certain-fields-of-certain-documents-with-a-single-r

Comment: Hi Seb, I want to apply above reduce way to merge document in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759830/how-can-merge-documentsonly-id-is-not-same-and-update-some-of-the-fields-valu  but then how can I update some field like update set with doc.field2: "checkclose" and status='closed'?

Comment: Hi Seb, I am stucking on this issue, can you help take a look?  thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788566/how-can-get-newest-document-just-using-the-map

Comment: do you know how can I get a result which is sorted within descending order of the “value” value? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800308/how-can-i-get-a-map-reduce-result-which-is-sorted-within-descending-order-of-the