# How to get from CouchDB only certain fields of certain documents with a single request?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

create a view that return only a subset of values from a document, each with its key and value within a json string. like if one given view returns a document as this following, Is it possible to get some fields information for a one request? thank you

`{
  "total_rows":10,
  "offset":3,
  "rows":[{
      "id":"doc1",
      "key":"abc123",
      "value": {
          "_id":"aaaa",
          "_rev":"bbb",
          "field1":"abc",
          "field2":"bcd",
          "field3":"cde",
          "field4":"123",
          "field5":"789",
          "field6":"aa@email.com",
          "field7":"ttt",
          "field8":"iii",
          "field9":[{
              "field91":"tyui",
              "field92":"55555"
          }],
          "field10"::"0000",
          "field11"::"55555",
          "field12"::"0030".........
      }
}`

I just want to create a view that returns some fields only the following:

`{
"field1":"abc",
"field2":"bcd",
"field3":"cde",
"field4":"123",
"field5":"789",
"field6":"aa@email.com",
"field7":"ttt",
"field8":"iii",
"field9":[{
            "field91":"tyui",
            "field92":"55555"
          }]
}`

Answer (score 2):

A map function that emits a new document with selected fields only. As an example, let's map field1 (a string) and field9 (an array) only:

```
function map(doc) {
  emit(doc._id, {
    field1: doc.field1, 
    field9: doc.field9
  });
}
```

In the above example, each document will be fired with a key being the original doc ID and the value being the mapped fields you require.
This is useful if you are planning to add a reduce function later.

Depending on your use case, you may just want to emit the mapped objects:

```
function map(doc) {
  emit({
    field1: doc.field1, 
    field9: doc.field9
  });
}
```

Please see http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html
The documentation on building data views is pretty good, you can discover a lot by experimenting..

Comment: Great thanks for your good suggestion and sharing the learning material

In this case, if field1 is the key, and I can get the selected 9 fields results like doc.field1 ="aaa", with the following:
function map(doc) {
  emit(doc.field1,{
    field1: doc.field1, 
 field2: doc.field2,
     .....
    field9: doc.field9
  });
}

and call http://...viewName?key="aaa",   the results include _id, key,and the value

But if I just want to get all the selected fields value with doc.field1 ="aaa", not included like the key and _id, what should I do?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid those coming back from CouchDB. But it shouldn't be difficult to 'get rid' of those fields client side, i.e.: map to another object (using javascript I guess, if this is a web app?). It is hard to tell without knowing your use case.

Comment: thank yo Seb, it is not web app I just do some practice on couchdb futon, I want to 'get rid' of those first fields like _id, key and value from the results:, :{"id":"xxxx","key":"xxxx","value": ............................btw, can I know your email or others that I can get touch with you?

Comment: hope you can advise me, why I can not run the results in couchdb like following map, what is wrong?                                                              function (doc) {
        var json_data = doc;
        json_data = json_data.rows;

       for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++)
        {
         var temp = json_data[i].value;
         delete temp._id;
         delete temp._rev;
         emit(null,{
        "field1": temp.field1, 
         "field2": temp.field2,
      "field3": temp.field3,
    .....
       });
        }
     }

Comment: You cannot get rid of the fields in question: id, key, value on couchdb side. You have to do it on your client. Whether the client is a web app served from somewhere else or maybe it is a couch app - does not matter. I don't understand why those field are a problem, could you please explain?

Comment: Hi Seb,not sure if it is okay to remove the  fields _id and _rev through a show function in couchdb?

Comment: Show function is meant to create a view (for display) of the data but I guess you can try it that way. Look at the list function too if you are dealing with multiple results.

Comment: thanks Seb, currently I am studying the couchdb,  I can define the display function in the design document in futon? btw,  I have question in my local couch db which have some duplication document results from map view results, I want to remove those duplicate, how can do this? thank you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453127/is-there-a-way-to-clear-duplication-record-from-results

Comment: Hi Seb, how to use reduce that merely takes the first document for any given key to remove duplicate document? stackoverflow.com/questions/37453127/is-there-a-way-to-clear-duplication-record-from-results

Comment: Hi Seb, can you help me take a look this map/reduce issue with merging some same values on some fields with some condition, thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759830/create-a-view-with-map-reduce-functions-that-return-same-values-with-some-crit