# How can get newest document just using the map

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have document like the following, I want to use map function to get the latest status with given UserId

```
doc1: _id=id1, UserId='ABC', status='OPEN',...
doc2: _id=id2, UserId='BCD',  status='OPEN', .....
doc3: _id=id3, UserId='ABC', status='CLOSED'....
```

For a given userid, if it related two status: open and close, then return that document with close status document

For a given userid, if it related just open status, then return that document with open status document

```
doc1: _id=id1, UserId='ABC', status='CLOSED',...
doc2: _id=id2, UserId='BCD',  status='OPEN', .....
```

I am trying do this as following map, if Userid is the same, , return the close status document, but not working,

```
function(doc) {
    var docArr = [];
        if (doc.event) {
       if(doc.UserId){
          docArr.push(doc)
          }
      }   
 for (var i=0; i<docArr.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if (docArr[i].UserId == docArr[j].UserId) {
        if (docArr[i].status == "CLOSED")
                  {
                   docArr.splice(j,1)
                  }
                  else(docArr[j].status == "CLOSED")
                  {
                   docArr.splice(i,1)
          }
    }
   }
}

for (var i=0; i<docArr.length; i++) {
    emit(docArr[i].UserId,docArr[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find all documents and their statuses for the same user ID, that's easy with a following map (example not case sensitive):

```
emit(doc.userId, doc.status)
```

then the reduce function could deal with finding the right status (your values will be docs of the same user id, with different statuses so you can loop through them finding the one with closed status or returning open if not found).

Comment: Thank you Seb, as your suggested I can use reduce to achieve on this,  The thing is how can I get the whole document with given a userid all at once, if in the map: I use emit(doc.userId, [doc.status,doc]),  I always get error of "reduce_overflow_error", "reason": "Reduce output must shrink more rapidly:

Comment: Hi Seb,  thank you your great help,  can you help me take a look this one: How can merge documents and if some fields in one document does not existed in another document(the key in the view is not existed in another one),   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759830/how-can-merge-documents-and-if-some-fields-in-one-document-does-not-existed-in-a

Comment: Hi Seb, thank you your great help, can you help me take a look this one: I am very stuck on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814311/how-to-get-documents-with-latest-status-in-case-some-fields-in-one-document-does

Comment: Hi Seb, I am so stuck on my client's request and really no idea on that hope you can help me out today, great thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814311/how-to-get-documents-with-latest-status-in-case-some-fields-in-one-document-does

Comment: Hi Seb,  can you help me take a look at this,,
 
if it is be possible to change what we emit in the reduce function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814311/how-to-get-documents-with-latest-status-in-case-some-fields-in-one-document-does.