# How to get documents with latest status in case some fields in one document does not existed in another document

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have some documents like following structure,  userid in doc1 is not existed in doc2,

```
doc1: userid='abc',  probNumber='123', status='OPEN',...
doc2: probNumber='123', status='CLOSE'.....
```

I want to get the latest status document according with the given doc.probNumber , But the key of the view would be doc.userid Or use doc.userid with doc.probNumber combination to achieve on that following

```
userid='abc',  probNumber='123', status='CLOSE',...
```

Here is the view and reduce if I used probNumber as the key to emit, But my client request me use userid as the key in the map to get the latest status ones with given same probNumber? if not, is it possible use doc.userid with doc.probNumber combination as the key in the map to get the latest status ones with given same probNumber?

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.probNumber) {
      emit(doc.probNumber, [doc.status]);
  }
}

  function(keys, values, rereduce) {
      var latest = values[0];
      var i = values.length;
      while (i--) {
        var val = values[i];
        if (val[0] == 'CLOSE') latest = val;
      }
      return latest;
    }
```

Comment: Is this results can be achieved by update handler function?  like combine or merge two document if some fields in one documents are not included within another document, and then merge them and then update with latest status. But I did not how do this? thank you

Comment: if it is be possible to change what we emit in the reduce function?